# FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected() returns false on certain Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I'm experiencing this error. I have referred to the previous questions asked about this but somehow I'm still unable to figure out how to add Samsung Pass SDK to the android project. It seems that Samsung has revamped its web site and the instructions given are not clear. Has anyone was able to configure Pass SDK to their existing projects?

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal)
 and 
[this](https://developer.samsung.com/tech-insights/pass/using-samsung-pass)

Comment: Samsung Pass SDK has been deprecated, see of bottom of: https://developer.samsung.com/services-and-apis Which Samsung devices running which version of Android?

Comment: @Morrison Chang. Thanks. I encountered this on Samsung Note 4 running version 6. If they have deprecated the Pass SDK, How to handle this on those devices?

Comment: Related: [Which Samsung devices do not support android's native fingerprint API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45499713/295004) Sadly Samsung has appeared to have completely removed the legacy Pass SDK section from their site.

Comment: Yeah... that's why I can't find it. Anyway, there should be a way to fix this right?

Comment: I faced same issue is there any solution ?